# Video subtitle not working my subtitle file is .txt

Tags: javascript, html, video

My subtitle file if .txt

```
<track src="subtitle.txt" kind="subtitles" srclang="ko" label="ko">
```

Can I subtitle as a .txt file?

```
video.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
video.textTracks[0].text;
```

I tried this but I get undefined

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your subtitle file needs to be formatted.
I suggest you use **.vtt** files.

> The HTML  element is used as a child of the media elements  and . It lets you specify timed text tracks (or time-based data), for example to automatically handle subtitles. **The tracks are formatted in WebVTT format (.vtt files) — Web Video Text Tracks or Timed Text Markup Language (TTML).**
>    [The Embed Text Track element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track)

Here are some helpful links:

[OpenSubtitles: download free subtitles](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/subs)

[Adding captions and subtitles to HTML5 video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video)

Comment: Do not count too much on links. A few tips extracted from that documentation will improve a lot your answer. And it will guarantee that the info will be available even if the link dies :)

Comment: If I have to use txt, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use .txt file for subtitles/caption.

The best format for HTML5 is **WebVTT (.vtt)**

> The **WebVTT** caption format is a text file with a .vtt extension. The
>   file begins with a header “WEBVTT FILE” followed by cues and their
>   corresponding text.

A WebVTT file looks something like this:

```
1
00:00:10.500 --> 00:00:13.000
NARRATOR: TEST CAPTION HERE,

2
00:00:15.000 --> 00:00:18.000
TEST CAPTION HERE.
```

Example Code:

```
<video height="240" width="320"><source src="/my_video_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<track default="" kind="captions" label="English" src="/captions_file.vtt" srclang="en-us">
<track kind="subtitles" label="French" src="/French_captions_file.vtt" srclang="fr"></video>
```